# Проблема с операционными системами.

Tags: windows

Пожалуйста, кто может объяснить, почему говорят, что невозможно поставить Windows xp, после того как стояла Windows 7. Образ хр не создавался. Говорят, что она не может читать 7. Это так? У меня Win 7 стоит. Хочу хр поставить. Она то ставится, но зависает сильно.

Comment: Я что-то не понял. Значит можно ставить хр, если стаяла 7? Мне сказали, что не могут хр поставить. Тем более, если я не сохранил ее образ, чтоб можно было как бы откат сделать. Я-то ставлю ее, не оригинал конечно. Может это оригинал нельзя поставить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть одна проблема - можно потерять 7-ку (в смысле не сможешь в нее грузиться) - т.к. в 7-ке используется загрузчик отличный от ХР. Потому и рекомендуют ставить сначала ХР потом 7. Если же 7-ка уже не нужна. Желательно переформатировать установочные разделы... (возможно - пересоздать, т.к. 7-ка создает доп. загрузочный раздел 100МБ который ХР не нужен...)

Answer (score 0):

Ты не сможешь запустить установку XP из Win 7, но установке через "биос" не важно что у тебя там стоит, 7-ка, 9-ка, линкус, фряха, мак без разницы, загрузчик делает своё дело - запускает установщик из нужного места (CD, Flash...) Затем тебе уже сама установка предложит диск куда можно будет поставить систему, желательно отформатировать его, и тогда будет всё ок.

Answer (score 0):

А ещё лучше поставить XP на виртуалку - есть такой режим Windows XP Mode - работает очень быстро и места на харде занимает столько, сколько нужно

Comment: Помимо ХР моде, (который, помимо всего прочего поддерживается не всеми процессорами - только теми, которые поддерживают аппаратную виртуализацию - сам столкнулся...) можно воспользоваться VMWare Player - новые версии имеют поддержку так называемого unite (?) режима - практически то же самое что обеспечивает ХР моде. Кроме того, поскольку в ХР моде используется "подключение к удаленному рабочему столу", (типа, RDP), некоторые вещи недоступны - например, попробуйте запустить 3Д игру в ХР моде... В VMWare этого недостатка (насколько я понимаю) нет...

Comment: да вы я гляжу извращенец - запускать 3д игру на виртуалке. У вас ведь виртуалка не на убунте стоять будет? - так в чём проблема запустить её на 7ке? Тем более проблемы с производительностью будут на любой системе виртуализации.

VMWare - не рекомендую потому что, у них многие сервисы загружаются при старте хостовой ОС - соответственно будет тормозить загрузка ОС и дополнительно сжираться память

Comment: 2alvin. гм. Какой вы скорый на выводы, однако. Вы уверены, что я не разработчик? У меня, например, систематически появляется необходимость протестировать 3д приложение под той или иной операционкой. Так может, мне из своего жесткого диска сделать нарезную колбасу? - Типа XP/Vista/7/Ubuntu/Slackware/RedHat/... ;) Да еще и перезагружаться каждый раз...

Answer (score 0):

А я сделал на много проще...ствится Windows7 а потом WindowsXP или наоборот разницы нет!!!И с Windows7 надо при помощи програмки EasyBCD 2.0 отредактировать загрузочный файлик...програмка элементарная с интуитивным интерфейсом!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ну, насколько мне известно, история сия пошла про висту, когда она появилась и стала массово устанавливаться на компьютеры и ноутбуки. Многие люди этому были как-то не особо рады и пытались ставить свою любимую и привычную пиратскую сборочку Windows ХР вместо лицензионной висты =)

А вместо IDE-накопителей стали в те же времена ставить SATA, для которых в стандартном установщике Windows XP драйверов не было и, соответственно, диска она не видела.
Люди, недолго думая, объяснили это магией и тем, что виста вредная, злая, ведьма и сжечь её, потому что она мешает ставить ХР.

ХР достаточно всё равно, что стояло перед ней) И если с драйверами всё в порядке (а теперь это не факт - кто-то для нового оборудования уже не делает драйвера для ХР), то всё прекрасно поставится и будет работать.

Comment: если он хочет удалить 7ку и поставить ХР то да, а если он будет ставить параллельно, то 7ка не будет видется при загрузке. Нужно тогда ещё как минимум GRUB поставить

Comment: Ну, вопрос состоял не в этом - что в какой последовательности ставить =)

А так да, не будет видеться. Но это всё прекрасно исправляется соответствующими командами =)